# How is this execution flow possible?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I've got a pretty straightforward Java webapp that has been showing some very strange behavior on development systems.  The problem starts with the registration handler, which is implented as follows:

```
//XXX:  this shouldn't really be 'synchronized', but I've declared it as such 
//      for the sake of debugging this issue
public synchronized ModelAndView submitRegister(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    String conf = request.getParameter("conf");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");

    EntityManager em = DatabaseUtil.getEntityManager(request);

    //[make sure required fields are present and valid, etc.]

    User user = getUserForEmail(email, em);
    if (user != null) {
        //[user already exists, go to error page]
    }

    //create the new user
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        user = new User();
        //[set fields, etc.]
        em.persist(user); 

        //[generate e-mail message contents]
        boolean validEmail = EmailUtility.sendEmail(admin, recip, subject, message, null, recip);
        if (validEmail) {

            em.getTransaction().commit();
            //[go to 'registration successful' page]
        }

        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        //[go to error page]
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        //[go to error page]
    }
}
```

The problem occurs on the `EmailUtility.sendEmail()` call.  The code for this method is pretty straightforward:

```
public static boolean sendEmail(String fromAddress, String to, String subject, String message, String fromHeaderValue, String toHeaderValue) {
    try {
        Session session = getMailSession(to);
        Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        if (fromHeaderValue != null) {
            mailMessage.setHeader("From", fromHeaderValue);
        }
        if (toHeaderValue != null) {
            mailMessage.setHeader("To", toHeaderValue);
        }
        mailMessage.setHeader("Date", new Date().toString());
        mailMessage.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setContent(message, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        Transport.send(mailMessage);
        return true;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        LOG.error("Failed to send e-mail!", e);
        return false;
    } 
}
```

What happens is that when the code reaches the call for `EmailUtility.sendEmail()`, instead of calling that method *execution recurses through submitRegister()*.  That's easily one of the most bizarre things I've ever seen.

For awhile I didn't even believe that was what's actually happening; but at this point I've confirmed it by synchronizing the method involved and adding print statements on every line of both methods.  `submitRegister()` recurses, and `sendEmail()` is never called.  I've got no idea how this is even possible.

Frustratingly, the *exact same code* runs just as it should on the production server.  It's only on development systems that this problem appears.

Any suggestions regarding what might be causing this problem and what I can do to fix it are welcome.

Comment: Are you debugging a release build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, This is not possible :)
I would suggest you strip away all other code, put in a lot of logging, if you don't like debugging and see what happens. Start with something like:

```
public synchronized ModelAndView submitRegister(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    LOG.debug("submitRegister: " + this.toString);
    EmailUtility.sendEmail("a@x.y", "b@x.y", "subject", "message", "from", "to");
}

public static boolean sendEmail(String fromAddress, String to, String subject, String message, String fromHeaderValue, String toHeaderValue) {
    LOG.debug("sendEmail: " + this.toString());
}
```

The `toString` will show you what classes are involved.
My guess would be that:

- your first call fails, so `sendEmail` will never be invoked
- `submitRegister` is triggered more than once by someone else, not by the `EmailUtility.sendEmail` statement.

If you get the stripped version to work, start putting back your code, one peace at a time to see where it all goes bad :)

Comment: This *should not* be possible, I agree 100%.  But it clearly is.  I have debug statements on the first line of each method, and `submitRegister()` is definitely called, and `sendMail()` is definitely not called.  The code definitely reaches the line that *should* call `sendEmail()`, and if I comment out the call to `sendEmail()` the method works normally.

Comment: I'm going to agree with Thobias' advice here. Strip down the extraneous stuff and just leave the problematic code. Does your problem still exist at that point? If so, it will probably be much easier to debug. If not, then start adding the other stuff back until the problem starts occurring again; then, you'll have a better idea of where the real problem is.

Comment: ok. Then you found something really cool! :) If you can prove it I would love to run it on my own.

Comment: @ThobiasBergqvist - No, it looks like I spoke too soon.  It appears that a combination of problems working together were causing this very bizarre execution flow without violating any fundamentals of the language semantics or runtime environment.

Comment: I'm still doubtful though. Anyways, What I would to next, after running the stripped code and observed the same behaviour, is to remove `synchronized`. I guess this is due to thread safety, but there is other ways of handeling that. And four your debugging sessions you don't need to worry about thread safety. Secondly, remove `static` in your email utility. My opinion is that it is errorprone. If there is no heavy initialization a `new EmailUtility` is preferable.

Comment: I posted an answer below describing what the issues were, if you're curious.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I tracked this down to a few different issues working together:

1. On development systems, the classpath was missing `javax.mail.Address`.  This caused the `EmailUtility` class to fail to initialize, and would throw a `NoClassDefFoundError` on the `sendEmail()` call, before any code from that method could execute.
2. The code in `submitRegister()` had a `catch Exception` block, but `NoClassDefFoundError` extends `Error`, not `Exception`.  So it bypassed the `catch Exception` block entirely.
3. The Spring controller where the `Error` was actually caught had some of the most questionable "error-handling" code I've ever come across:

   ```
   try {
       Method serviceMethod = this.getControllerClass().getMethod(method, HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class);
       if (this.doesMethodHaveAnnotation(serviceMethod, SynchronizedPerAccount.class)) {
           synchronized(this.getAccountLock(request)) {
               super.doService(request, response);
           }
       }
       else {
           //don't need to execute synchronously
           super.doService(request, response);
       }
   }
   catch (Throwable ignored) {
       super.doService(request, response);
   }
   ```

So the `NoClassDefFoundError` was propagating back up to the Spring controller, which was catching it and attempting to re-invoke the `doService()` method, which caused `submitRegister()` to be invoked again.  It wasn't recursion (though there was no way to tell that by just looking at the debug output), it was the Spring controller calling it twice for the same request.  It never got called more than twice for a given request, because there's no try/catch around the second `doService()` call.

Long story short, I patched up these issues and problem solved.

Comment: Ok ... interesting. The first 2 point I guess is resonable, but the reinvocation in the 3:de is scary. It is probably documented in some obscure documentation somewhere, but not what I would expect. Nice investigation though. I guess the lesson here is to catch Throwable instead of Exception in these kinds of circumstances.